# Arranging huxtable with gridExtra

Tags: gridextra, huxtable

I need to use the gridExtra package to get the page view I want in my project. I created the tables in the project with huxtable and created a theme myself. I used the gridExtra package because I want these tables to be grouped as I want and displayed in a certain order on the page, but **when I run the script, I either get an error or the table format is out of huxtable**. When I want to bring a chart and a huxtable together, **the format doesnt remain as huxtable even though it detects the table**. How can I use huxtable and gridExtra at the same time?